# Missing closing paranthes MySQL workbench, Query syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my code:

```
SELECT Lname
    ,Fname
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM WORKS_ON B
        WHERE (
                B.Pno IN (
                    SELECT Pnumber
                    FROM PROJECT
                    WHERE Dnum = 5
                        AND NOT EXISTS (
                            SELECT *
                            FROM WORKS_ON C
                            WHERE C.Essn = Ssn
                                AND C.Pno = B.Pno
                            )
                    )
                );
```

It is almost true but it doesn't work error message : Missing closing parenthesis

Answer (score 3):

*Closing parenthesis* is that `)` thing on the end. The error is telling you that you have four `(`'s, but only three `)`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Because you missing a `)` at the end of your query.

```
SELECT Lname, Fname FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM WORKS_ON B WHERE 
    ( 

        B.Pno IN 
        (   SELECT Pnumber FROM PROJECT WHERE Dnum=5 AND NOT EXISTS
            (   SELECT * FROM WORKS_ON C WHERE C.Essn=Ssn AND C.Pno=B.Pno)
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always remember opening and closing of brackets `()` it is better when you start writing query first open and close brackets and then write query

In your code count of open brackets not equal to close brackets